# Inconsistent behaviour of Tkinter Gui

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a very simple GUI. with just one button.
In fact, I tried to replicate this code https://pythonprogramming.net/tkinter-python-3-tutorial-adding-buttons/

However, I am using Python 2.7 unlike the article which uses, Python 3.x
The same code in when run in Python 2.7 does not show the Quit Button, where as in the video it shows the Quit Button.

Here is my code

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()


    def init_window(self):

        # changing the title of our master widget
        self.master.title("Gui")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack()

        # creating a button instance
        button = Button(self , text = 'quit')

        # placing the button on my window
        button.place(x=0, y=0)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()

    #size of the window
    root.geometry("400x300")

    app = Window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

and here is the code from the tutorial

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    #Creation of init_window
    def init_window(self):

        # changing the title of our master widget
        self.master.title("GUI")

        # allowing the widget to take the full space of the root window
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # creating a button instance
        quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit")

        # placing the button on my window
        quitButton.place(x=0, y=0)

root = Tk()

#size of the window
root.geometry("400x300")

app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Could anyone explain the difference in behaviour?

Comment: you missed to this in 2.7 `self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)`, provide parameters to `pack`.

Comment: Thanks this works,  but instead I retained 
        self.pack()
and changed button = Button(self , text = 'quit') to button = Button(self.master , text = 'quit') and this works well. Could anyone explain what is happening internally